# JAX-WS specification and the need for JAXB annotations

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I always thought that to bind beans to SOAP messages in JAX-WS we need to use JAXB bindings.

Recently I was able to send and receive complex beans without the need of any JAXB annotations using Metro implementation.

Is this a new feature introduced in the latest specification or was it like this from the start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are default behaviours that JAXB will use to map classes that aren't annotated. You only *need* annotations if the mapping you want to define doesn't follow these defaults (e.g. if you want to map anything to attributes rather than elements, or override the element names, add wrapper elements round collections, etc.).

Comment: thanks. this default behavior existed from the beginning? When would someone want to override the defaults, maybe when client accepts a differently structured SOAP response?

Comment: @John it certainly worked like that when I wrote services back in 2007 or so. If you start with a WSDL and generate code then it'll be fully annotated by the generator, if you're working code first I would start by generating a WSDL from the un-annotated code, then add annotations for anything you want to tweak.